# Skype for Business Server 2015 set up on Standard Front End Server

Tags: skype, skype-for-business-2016

I'm following this link to set up a skype for business server 2015.

http://windowspbx.blogspot.in/2015/05/installing-skype-for-business-2015.html

I dont understand if we really need two server machines.
Also I need to know which all part to be done in Server machine and which all to be done in the AD server machine

Answer (score 1):

The [article by Matt Landis](https://windowspbx.blogspot.fi/2015/05/installing-skype-for-business-2015.html) you are reading is a step by step guide for one kind of Skype for Business Server 2015 installation, with one *Domain Controller* and one *Skype for Business Front End Server*. That's an example of a **very little topology**. As said in Skype for Business Server [Topology Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn933894.aspx):

> Before preparing anything else, you’ll want to know you’re planning
>   for the right topology for your deployment of Skype for Business
>   Server 2015. The first thing you need to decide is if you’re going to
>   have an on-premises deployment of Skype for Business Server 2015, or
>   if you’re going to combine this with a Skype for Business Server
>   Online deployment in a Hybrid deployment.

There's also information on which server roles needs to be on a separate server ([server collocation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn933894.aspx#Server%20collocation%20in%20Skype%20for%20Business%20Server%202015)).

Then, if you look at [Reference topologies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398095.aspx), you'll soon notice that even the reference topology for a small organization has several servers, and the topology map only contains Skype for Business server roles; the AD server roles falls outside the map. The *small organization* also has 4000 users.

These are all indications that if you have a tiny organization with only one server:

- The [Skype for Business Online](https://products.office.com/en/skype-for-business/online), i.e. same as a service, is designed for your organization.
- You should still have at least a backup domain controller.

If you still wish to use just two servers and do as Matt Landis guides you, Microsoft Hyper-V is free; you can separate the roles on different virtual machines on a single physical server.

Comment: I'm installing an evaluation to try out some automation. So Installing Server is just for my work. not for the organisation.

Comment: Please don't evaluate anything on a Domain Controller of a production environment! The fact that it's your organizations only DC makes it even worse. Set up a separated test environment, instead.

Comment: Yeah. Done that. Also the domain is an isolated one. so no issues that way.

Comment: That's good to hear! If you just need the server for testing something else, I'd suggest doing exactly as in the tutorial. That way you'll know that if something goes wrong, it's because of the test you are performing, not the basic configuration.

Comment: can you take a look at [this Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/850354/active-directory-certificate-services-set-up-for-skype-for-business-setup)